# Why was Choi's ice stone empty?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

When Naksu was in Gwido, she noted that the ice stone that belonged to Shaman Choi's ancestor was empty and did not contain any energy.

However, we know that other ice stones, such as the one that eventually arrived to Jang Uk, can last that long without losing their energy, and there is no sign that the energy of the ice stone, occasionally described as "inexhaustible," can be depleted by use.

Why was the ice stone in Gwido depleted?